# Gravar ListView no Banco SQL usando Entity Framework e C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, winforms, listview

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop de vendas utilizando C# e Entity Framework e estou com dúvidas quanto a gravação do itens inseridos na `ListView` no banco de dados SQL.

Como fazer para gravar os itens inseridos na `ListView` na minha tabela `tb_itens_venda` no banco?

Para inserir os itens no `ListView` estou usando o seguinte código:

```
private void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ListaPedidoItem.AddNew();

    vwProduto produto = new vwProduto();
    ProdutoBLL objProduto = new ProdutoBLL();

    produto = objProduto.FindBy(txtCodBarras.Text);

    PedidoItem item = new PedidoItem();
    item.CodigoProduto = txtCodBarras.Text;
    item.Quantidade = int.Parse(txtQuantidade.Text);
    item.ValorUnitario = produto.PrecoVenda;

    PreencheGrid(item);
}
```

E o metodo `PreencheGrid`

```
private void PreencheGrid(PedidoItem item)
{
    //listView1.Items.Clear();

    ProdutoBLL objProduto = new ProdutoBLL();

    vwProduto entidade = objProduto.FindBy(item.CodigoProduto);
    ListViewItem novoitem = new ListViewItem(entidade.CodigoBarras);

    novoitem.SubItems.Add(entidade.Descricao);
    novoitem.SubItems.Add(item.Quantidade.ToString());
    novoitem.SubItems.Add(((decimal)item.ValorUnitario).ToString("C"));
    novoitem.SubItems.Add(((decimal)item.ValorUnitario * item.Quantidade).ToString("C"));

    listView1.Items.Add(novoitem);

    // PedidoItem é minha classe DTO.
    this.itens.Add(new PedidoItem()
    {
         CodigoProduto = entidade.CodigoBarras,
         DescricaoProduto = entidade.Descricao,
         Quantidade = int.Parse(entidade.Quantidade),
         ValorUnitario = entidade.PrecoVenda
    });
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema no seu código para gravar? Dá algum erro? O que acontece?

Comment: Tenho um botão gravar que ainda nao executa nenhuma ação devido não saber como fazer para pegar esses itens inseridos no ListView e gravar

Comment: Não seria melhor gravar o item no banco e depois fazer um update no listview com os itens que estão no banco?

Answer (score 1):

No botão gravar você vai colocar o CommandName = "Update" ou "Insert" vai implementa o evento OnItemCommand da listview dentro do metodo você vai pegar o eventArgs Item e atráves desse controle você consegue pega os outros usando Item.FindControl("controlName"); depois é só definir os valores nas propriedades do objeto e salvar.

```
   protected void ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = e.Item;

 switch (e.CommandName)
        {
 case "Insert":
var controle = item.FindControl("controlId");
/*Escreva a logica para obter os valores da tela*/
 break;

         }

/*Escreva a logica para salvar os valores*/

 }
```

você vai ter que implementar o OnItemInserting e/ou OnItemUpdating do listview